# JavaScript Chrome Extension: "AbortError: The user aborted a request." error

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, chrome-extension-manifest-v2

I got `Uncaught (in promise) AbortError: The user aborted a request.` error after clicking on my popup button, and selecting a folder on my computer

**Popup.js**

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

    document.getElementById('btnCreate').addEventListener('click', async function() {

      // Request permission to write to the file system
      const handle = await window.showDirectoryPicker();

      // Create a new directory inside the selected directory
      await handle.getDirectoryHandle('myFolder', { create: true });

  });  //<--- This is the line which my chrome debugger shows which (probably) problem happens and I don't know why
})
```

Comment: Sounds like a bug in Chrome. Try choosing the file in a `web_accessible_resources` iframe in the current page.

Comment: @wOxxOm: bug reports linked in answer below.

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug; `showDirectoryPicker` doesn't work in extensions. See [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1368818), [here](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1359786), etc. It doesn't look like a fix is imminent.